# parsing a file in php using one word

Tags: php

I've been struggling with this for days and I cant imagine it being hard but I'm new to PHP and stuck on this one.

I only want lines not starting "BWAH013" unless the previous line starts "BWAH013" in which case I want that line too.

Input:

```
BWAH013    12-32-1443  specials
BWAH013    17-52-1412  regular
BWAH013    72-43-3212  specials
BWAH013    43-11-5332  specials
otaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
itpSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
draDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
itoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BWAH013    64-12-6432  specials
BWAH013    19-22-6422  regular
BWAH013    14-98-5432  specials
itaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
itpSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
draDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
itoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BWAH013    56-76-8754  regular
BWAH013    76-66-9864  specials
BWAH013    43-54-3255  regular
awaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
itpSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
draDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
itoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BWAH013    68-19-2343  specials
BWAH013    75-32-5312  regular
```

Output:

```
BWAH013    43-11-5332  specials
otaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
itpSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
draDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
itoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BWAH013    14-98-5432  specials
itaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
itpSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
draDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
itoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BWAH013    43-54-3255  regular
awaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
itpSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
draDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
itoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Do you have an example of code you have tried to parse the file? If yes, please add this in your question. This make it more easier for experts to answer your question

Comment: i have none worth showing.

Comment: @j-doep Note that you can't ask people on Stackoverflow for writing your codes. I see you are new here, so I would recommend you to read this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Without any codes you have tried by yourself, this will be difficult for us to answer your question for your problem in your scripts.

Comment: i know but it is worth the try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to break your `input` into individual lines using [explode](http://php.net/explode) and then [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) line check  if it starts with a "BWAH013" using [strpos](http://php.net/strpos). You can also store the line in a variable to check against.

Something like this (a rought draft; not tested but you get the idea):

```
<?php
$input = <<< EOT
BWAH013    12-32-1443  specials
BWAH013    17-52-1412  regular
BWAH013    72-43-3212  specials
BWAH013    43-11-5332  specials
otaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
itpSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
draDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
itoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BWAH013    64-12-6432  specials
BWAH013    19-22-6422  regular
BWAH013    14-98-5432  specials
itaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
itpSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
draDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
itoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BWAH013    56-76-8754  regular
BWAH013    76-66-9864  specials
BWAH013    43-54-3255  regular
awaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
itpSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
draDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
itoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BWAH013    68-19-2343  specials
BWAH013    75-32-5312  regular
EOT;

$lines = explode("\n", $input);
$previous = null;
$result == '';
foreach ($lines AS $line) {
    // If this line doesn't start BWAH013, the previous line is not null and the previous line starts BWAH013, then add the previous line.
    if (substr($line, 0, 7) != 'BWAH013' && !is_null($previous) && substr($previous, 0, 7) == 'BWAH013') {
       $result .= $previous . PHP_EOL;
    }

    // Add this line if it does not start BWAH013.
    if (substr($line, 0, 7) != 'BWAH013') {
       $result .= $line . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $previous = $line;
}

echo $result;
```